# How to use testng annotions for appium automation?

Tags: testng, appium

Say Base class is:

```
package tutcheck;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File f = new File("src");
        File fs=new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "192.168.56.101:5555");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,fs.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    }
}
```

and other class is:

```
package tutcheck;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class Gestures extends Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        AndroidDriver < AndroidElement > driver = Capabilities();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Views\").instance(0))").click();
        //driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']").click();

        TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
        t.tap(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']")).perform();
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1. Custom Adapter']").click();

        t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).release().perform();
        //t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).release().perform();
        System.out.println(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sample menu']").getText());

    }
}
```

So now my question is that how do I get rid of main method firstly in the gestures.java class, also how do I use testng annotations in both the base class and call the other classes using testng annotations for the other classes as well?

Answer (score 0):

*Hi you can create a Test Base class as **BaseTest.java** where you will initialize the **AndroidDriver** and a test class as **Test.java** which will extend the **BaseTest.java** and use the driver for performing the driver actions.*

Below is the sample code for BaseTest.java :

```
package com.edf.mobile.tests;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class BaseTest {
    public AppiumDriver<?> driver;
    //initialize your driver here
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest(){
        File f = new File("src");
        File fs=new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "192.168.56.101:5555");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,fs.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Test.java class is as below :

```
package com.edf.mobile.tests;

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AppiumTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementsByXPath("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Views\").instance(0))");
        //driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']").click();

        TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
        t.tap(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']")).perform();
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1. Custom Adapter']").click();

        t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).release().perform();
        //t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).release().perform();
        System.out.println(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sample menu']").getText());

    }
}
```

Note : if above code is not working for you then, just try changing the appium java-client version, selenium version to latest. As most of the methods are deprecated in current version you might want to update above code.

**This should give you an idea of how to use testng annotations, and how to get rid of java main method.**

TestNG provides many more annotions which you can explore on official testng site.